# Implicit Invocation of Google Assistant Action App with DialogFlow not working

Tags: json, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I'm getting the

> "API Version 2: Failed to parse JSON response string with 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' error: \": Cannot find field.\"."

and so am hoping you can help me, as I cannot get Implicit Invoking working for my app.

I've attached screenshots of the Welcome Intent setup on DialogFLow as well as pasted the Google Cloud fail logs here:

Google Cloud **FAIL** LOGS:

```
{
  "request": {
    "conversationToken": "",
    "debugLevel": 1,
    "inputType": "KEYBOARD",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "mockLocation": {
      "city": "Mountain View",
      "coordinates": {
        "latitude": 37.421980615353675,
        "longitude": -122.08419799804688
      },
      "formattedAddress": "Googleplex, Mountain View, CA 94043, United States",
      "zipCode": "94043"
    },
    "query": "ask follow-up to log a call",
    "surface": "GOOGLE_HOME"
  },
  "response": {
    "conversationToken": "GidzaW11bG...",
    "response": "Follow up isn't responding right now. Try again soon.",
    "visualResponse": {
      "visualElements": []
    }
  },
  "debug": {
    "agentToAssistantDebug": {
      "agentToAssistantJson": "{\"message\":\"Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse, exception thrown with message: Empty speech response\",\"apiResponse\":{\"id\":\"875b123f-bcb2-4f45-b2f4-10193a6132c3\",\"timestamp\":\"2018-01-30T06:33:52.773Z\",\"lang\":\"en-us\",\"result\":{},\"status\":{\"code\":200,\"errorType\":\"success\"},\"sessionId\":\"1517294032097\"}}"
    },
    "assistantToAgentDebug": {
      "assistantToAgentJson": "{\"user\":{\"userId\":\"ABwppHHDarg-rpyAaSt0hm8TZaycr30xhUpQcRKfchRbXriPUKmmzi_BqQrpXInBGyGmgfF4yIEiMX0jInJ8rQ\",\"accessToken\":\"{\\\"access_token\\\":\\\"00D3600000uHY5!AQoAQAcyjXEI.J.5EnB4.R.EdNXBKlymGOI4I6PPJVb465uyQLxnbQDyjPHtD0uE0W1RMdhnhgXLEpr8qPIMOTcnvsfKH0j\\\",\\\"signature\\\":\\\"etNbI3erh1iYmsTqCRicfKKJknRtGnCb1esvufdg7g=\\\",\\\"scope\\\":\\\"refresh_token web api\\\",\\\"instance_url\\\":\\\"https://follow-up-ed.my.salesforce.com\\\",\\\"id\\\":\\\"https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D3600000uHY5EAM/0053600000L9ePAAS\\\",\\\"token_type\\\":\\\"Bearer\\\",\\\"issued_at\\\":\\\"1517293582207\\\"}\",\"locale\":\"en-US\",\"lastSeen\":\"2018-01-30T06:26:14Z\"},\"conversation\":{\"conversationId\":\"151729432097\",\"type\":\"NEW\"},\"inputs\":[{\"intent\":\"Log Call by Business\",\"rawInputs\":[{\"inputType\":\"VOICE\",\"query\":\"ask follow-up to log a call\"}],\"arguments\":[{\"name\":\"trigger_query\",\"rawText\":\"log a call\",\"textValue\":\"log a call\"},{\"name\":\"Type\",\"rawText\":\"call\",\"textValue\":\"call\"}]}],\"surface\":{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO\"}]},\"isInSandbox\":true,\"availableSurfaces\":[{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"}]}]}",
      "curlCommand": "curl -v 'https://api.api.ai/api/integrations/google?token=1ee421e5c9504f5b995ce9df62f7d275' -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -H 'Google-Actions-API-Version: 2' -H 'Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjI2YzAxOGIyMzNmZTJlZWY0N2ZlZGJiZGQ5Mzk4MTcwZmM5YjI5ZDgifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJzYWxlc2ZvcmNlLWEwOWVkIiwiYXpwIjoiMTE4NDUyMTUyMjE5LW1zZ2VldXBkaGU5YWp0MzZpNnJxbHJtdTExZGQ1Y2gyLmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNTE3Mjk0MTUyLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FjY291bnRzLmdvb2dsZS5jb20iLCJqdGkiOiI5ZTJjOGI1OGQzZjRiNTc3MmQ0MDc2ZjIwNWIyMGEyYTdmYTQ3MGY3IiwiaWF0IjoxNTE3Mjk0MDMyLCJuYmYiOjE1MTcyOTM3MzJ9.WnIVnDFUESVaLYOITacgDzS_4qPCat8YEMTHgsSzvHUzJNNeZ3oaDqUZ5lwECI0jfp2qHpW7Il5Tv1iDyPScOeggvm2cZZa4OXdr7PLr362eT5wyOZnsFWlrU8n4KlNZsuKl_uMSxhftP0qD2eUuwAKQ0bbAPurApTF_iY8Gzh2V0QYpn1Ol06bJLJo8B9z4lXmFuGfzldjWXojQ1eA794nItQKtt2X7tiSfBOoXOL2fpT8omy293vcMI-dWtf5FY1nH9_bN1GKHCbOQ4LiJTB__r7PVHOcq-SNb9_CtKaXvrLo9EW3CyfnHlc0SGv1UUo9akbvDZEwZG9B3gH7K1g'  -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Cloud-Functions/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)' -X POST -d '{\"user\":{\"userId\":\"ABwppHHDarg-rpyAaSt0hm8TZaycr30xhUpQcRKfchRbXriPUKmmzi_BqQrpXInBGyGmgfF4yIEiMX0jInJ8rQ\",\"accessToken\":\"{\\\"access_token\\\":\\\"00D36000000uHY5!AQoAQAcyjXEI.J.5EnB4.R.EdNXBKlymGOI4I6PPJVb465uyQLxnbQDyjPHtD0uE0W1RMdhnhgXL8Epr8qPIMOTcnvsfKH0j\\\",\\\"signature\\\":\\\"etNbI3erh1iYmsTqCRicfKKJknRtGnC4b1esvufdg7g=\\\",\\\"scope\\\":\\\"refresh_token web api\\\",\\\"instance_url\\\":\\\"https://follow-up-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com\\\",\\\"id\\\":\\\"https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D36000000uHY5EAM/00536000000L9ePAAS\\\",\\\"token_type\\\":\\\"Bearer\\\",\\\"issued_at\\\":\\\"1517293582207\\\"}\",\"locale\":\"en-US\",\"lastSeen\":\"2018-01-30T06:26:14Z\"},\"conversation\":{\"conversationId\":\"1517294032097\",\"type\":\"NEW\"},\"inputs\":[{\"intent\":\"Log Call by Business\",\"rawInputs\":[{\"inputType\":\"VOICE\",\"query\":\"ask follow-up to log a call\"}],\"arguments\":[{\"name\":\"trigger_query\",\"rawText\":\"log a call\",\"textValue\":\"log a call\"},{\"name\":\"Type\",\"rawText\":\"call\",\"textValue\":\"call\"}]}],\"surface\":{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO\"}]},\"isInSandbox\":true,\"availableSurfaces\":[{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"}]}]}'"
    },
    "sharedDebugInfo": [
      {
        "name": "ResponseValidation",
        "subDebugEntry": [
          {
            "debugInfo": "API Version 2: Failed to parse JSON response string with 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' error: \": Cannot find field.\".",
            "name": "UnparseableJsonResponse"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "errors": [
    [
      {
        "debugInfo": "API Version 2: Failed to parse JSON response string with 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' error: \": Cannot find field.\".",
        "name": "UnparseableJsonResponse"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Google Cloud **SUCCESS** LOGS:

```
{
  "request": {
    "conversationToken": "",
    "debugLevel": 1,
    "inputType": "KEYBOARD",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "mockLocation": {
      "city": "Mountain View",
      "coordinates": {
        "latitude": 37.421980615353675,
        "longitude": -122.08419799804688
      },
      "formattedAddress": "Googleplex, Mountain View, CA 94043, United States",
      "zipCode": "94043"
    },
    "query": "Talk to Follow-Up",
    "surface": "GOOGLE_HOME"
  },
  "response": {
    "conversationToken": "CiZDIzVhNm...",
    "expectUserResponse": true,
    "response": "Follow-Up is Online. Would you like to log a call, add a note or create a reminder?",
    "visualResponse": {
      "visualElements": []
    }
  },
  "debug": {
    "agentToAssistantDebug": {
      "agentToAssistantJson": "{\"conversationToken\":\"[\\\"defaultwelcomeintent-followup\\\",\\\"sessiondata\\\"]\",\"expectUserResponse\":true,\"expectedInputs\":[{\"inputPrompt\":{\"richInitialPrompt\":{\"items\":[{\"simpleResponse\":{\"textToSpeech\":\"Follow-Up is Online. Would you like to log a call, add a note or create a reminder?\",\"displayText\":\"Follow-Up is Online. Would you like to log a call, add a note or create a reminder in Salesforce?\"}}],\"suggestions\":[{\"title\":\"Log a call\"},{\"title\":\"Add a note\"},{\"title\":\"Create a reminder\"},{\"title\":\"Exit\"}]}},\"possibleIntents\":[{\"intent\":\"assistant.intent.action.TEXT\"},{\"intent\":\"907faabf-33a2-49ff-a368-263d01e812fc\"},{\"intent\":\"a4bdf329-5430-4833-827d-620ed00e4288\"},{\"intent\":\"68d2be51-880d-44dd-9939-1c09089b5fbf\"},{\"intent\":\"d9f56992-363e-410d-a00e-1e9a59ed613d\"},{\"intent\":\"66de3f32-c11a-4e36-80b1-64582bc1ef69\"},{\"intent\":\"befff469-3348-49d7-b9d6-5bbe7eef2aa6\"},{\"intent\":\"a813eeba-2a35-4f20-8fdb-09f8e9b08b7c\"},{\"intent\":\"e9add01c-1067-4c14-a48c-979f4934e192\"},{\"intent\":\"1dbe2f1a-a12e-4f22-9092-11dafce0cf26\"},{\"intent\":\"94c36f7f-8fff-4c55-b6f4-f5556fa83d8a\"},{\"intent\":\"d503d957-6dea-4d40-b161-adb779df2f66\"},{\"intent\":\"040b1388-4aaa-4e3b-8af9-67c111bd9cc7\"},{\"intent\":\"494afd87-d03a-49a6-a5da-340061c9121a\"}],\"speechBiasingHints\":[\"$Classification\",\"$Type\",\"$BusinessName\",\"$Task\",\"$FollowUp\",\"$Calendar\"]}],\"responseMetadata\":{\"status\":{},\"queryMatchInfo\":{\"queryMatched\":true,\"intent\":\"6bb1ee8e-8a54-4422-b20e-de50839c40bc\"}}}"
    },
    "assistantToAgentDebug": {
      "assistantToAgentJson": "{\"user\":{\"userId\":\"ABwppHHDarg-rpyAaSt0hm8TZaycr30xhUpQcRKfchRbXriPUKmmzi_BqQrpXInBGyGmgfF4yIEiMX0jInJ8rQ\",\"accessToken\":\"{\\\"access_token\\\":\\\"00D36000000uHY5!AQoAQAcyjXEI.J.5EnB4.R.EdNXBKlymGOI4I6PPJVb465uyQLxnbQDyjPHtD0uE0W1RMdhnhgXL8Epr8qPIMOTcnvsfKH0j\\\",\\\"signature\\\":\\\"etNbI3erh1iYmsTqCRicfKKJknRtGnC4b1esvufdg7g=\\\",\\\"scope\\\":\\\"refresh_token web api\\\",\\\"instance_url\\\":\\\"https://follow-up-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com\\\",\\\"id\\\":\\\"https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D36000000uHY5EAM/00536000000L9ePAAS\\\",\\\"token_type\\\":\\\"Bearer\\\",\\\"issued_at\\\":\\\"1517293582207\\\"}\",\"locale\":\"en-US\",\"lastSeen\":\"2018-01-30T06:33:52Z\"},\"conversation\":{\"conversationId\":\"1517294128019\",\"type\":\"NEW\"},\"inputs\":[{\"intent\":\"actions.intent.MAIN\",\"rawInputs\":[{\"inputType\":\"VOICE\",\"query\":\"Talk to Follow-Up\"}]}],\"surface\":{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"}]},\"isInSandbox\":true,\"availableSurfaces\":[{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"}]}]}",
      "curlCommand": "curl -v 'https://api.api.ai/api/integrations/google?token=1ee421e5c9504f5b995ce9df62f7d275' -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -H 'Google-Actions-API-Version: 2' -H 'Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjI2YzAxOGIyMzNmZTJlZWY0N2ZlZGJiZGQ5Mzk4MTcwZmM5YjI5ZDgifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJzYWxlc2ZvcmNlLWEwOWVkIiwiYXpwIjoiMTE4NDUyMTUyMjE5LW1zZ2VldXBkaGU5YWp0MzZpNnJxbHJtdTExZGQ1Y2gyLmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNTE3Mjk0MjQ4LCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FjY291bnRzLmdvb2dsZS5jb20iLCJqdGkiOiIxY2M5ODYxOGVlNzI5NzQ4YjdiZTczZmI3NjY2ZDM3YzllYjk0ZDQ4IiwiaWF0IjoxNTE3Mjk0MTI4LCJuYmYiOjE1MTcyOTM4Mjh9.S28YQqlVGJEK0xXfgZ-rxgwdXlfBMBoV3UXBIsvN6SeKK3PYvkvShqpKB5Icr89TSvzS7riq2H9YBwzrvPCRQscrH_3tVRyQL2EsCQhnpGQhnvVdO7rwE2b1-xnoAj7dy9D8EOuNskOK7V2Qek7u-_ZdU9r7w4W_saVwhyFtGMjfXFjgPgRurZq3Ei3-fnZ9GJ-3RqlgGU8FiSSFXheBgSvwWq9Ai7QeiVDaGcjxovX1qZXhkhu9W5lPPdTE1tUYVZ3CZcJfE5YqQiPJfQj6OJwguRg5Qb3aKMHlBV50Pb5Ux302ZWT_L49lVxk-cFM0-oTeNo5YLuFzQIwCgpcaoA'  -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Cloud-Functions/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)' -X POST -d '{\"user\":{\"userId\":\"ABwppHHDarg-rpyAaSt0hm8TZaycr30xhUpQcRKfchRbXriPUKmmzi_BqQrpXInBGyGmgfF4yIEiMX0jInJ8rQ\",\"accessToken\":\"{\\\"access_token\\\":\\\"00D36000000uHY5!AQoAQAcyjXEI.J.5EnB4.R.EdNXBKlymGOI4I6PPJVb465uyQLxnbQDyjPHtD0uE0W1RMdhnhgXL8Epr8qPIMOTcnvsfKH0j\\\",\\\"signature\\\":\\\"etNbI3erh1iYmsTqCRicfKKJknRtGnC4b1esvufdg7g=\\\",\\\"scope\\\":\\\"refresh_token web api\\\",\\\"instance_url\\\":\\\"https://follow-up-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com\\\",\\\"id\\\":\\\"https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D36000000uHY5EAM/00536000000L9ePAAS\\\",\\\"token_type\\\":\\\"Bearer\\\",\\\"issued_at\\\":\\\"1517293582207\\\"}\",\"locale\":\"en-US\",\"lastSeen\":\"2018-01-30T06:33:52Z\"},\"conversation\":{\"conversationId\":\"1517294128019\",\"type\":\"NEW\"},\"inputs\":[{\"intent\":\"actions.intent.MAIN\",\"rawInputs\":[{\"inputType\":\"VOICE\",\"query\":\"Talk to Follow-Up\"}]}],\"surface\":{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"}]},\"isInSandbox\":true,\"availableSurfaces\":[{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"}]}]}'"
    }
  },
  "errors": []
}
```

And the DialogFLow JSON blob here:
**FAIL** DIALOGFLOW

```
{
  "id": "60acafcf-ceb2-485c-b3f6-663407832e1c",
  "timestamp": "2018-01-30T06:39:56.632Z",
  "lang": "en",
  "result": {
    "source": "agent",
    "resolvedQuery": "ask follow up to log a call",
    "action": "input.welcome",
    "actionIncomplete": false,
    "parameters": {},
    "contexts": [
      {
        "name": "defaultwelcomeintent-followup",
        "parameters": {},
        "lifespan": 2
      },
      {
        "name": "sessiondata",
        "parameters": {},
        "lifespan": 1
      }
    ],
    "metadata": {
      "intentId": "6bb1ee8e-8a54-4422-b20e-de50839c40bc",
      "webhookUsed": "true",
      "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
      "webhookResponseTime": 340,
      "intentName": "Default Welcome Intent"
    },
    "fulfillment": {
      "messages": [
        {
          "type": "suggestion_chips",
          "platform": "google",
          "suggestions": [
            {
              "title": "\"Log a call\""
            },
            {
              "title": "\"Add a note\""
            },
            {
              "title": "\"Create a reminder\""
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": 0,
          "speech": "Follow-Up isn't responding right now. Please try again later."
        }
      ]
    },
    "score": 0.5
  },
  "status": {
    "code": 200,
    "errorType": "success",
    "webhookTimedOut": false
  },
  "sessionId": "24069c06-d6c0-4723-a0d9-fa284884d023"
}
```

**SUCCESS** DIALOGFLOW

```
{
  "id": "210514e2-6702-4d30-9689-eb3279fdde6d",
  "timestamp": "2018-01-30T06:41:19.848Z",
  "lang": "en",
  "result": {
    "source": "agent",
    "resolvedQuery": "talk to follow up",
    "action": "input.welcome",
    "actionIncomplete": false,
    "parameters": {},
    "contexts": [
      {
        "name": "defaultwelcomeintent-followup",
        "parameters": {},
        "lifespan": 2
      },
      {
        "name": "sessiondata",
        "parameters": {},
        "lifespan": 1
      }
    ],
    "metadata": {
      "intentId": "6bb1ee8e-8a54-4422-b20e-de50839c40bc",
      "webhookUsed": "true",
      "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
      "webhookResponseTime": 237,
      "intentName": "Default Welcome Intent"
    },
    "fulfillment": {
      "messages": [
        {
          "type": "suggestion_chips",
          "platform": "google",
          "suggestions": [
            {
              "title": "\"Log a call\""
            },
            {
              "title": "\"Add a note\""
            },
            {
              "title": "\"Create a reminder\""
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": 0,
          "speech": "Follow-Up isn't responding right now. Please try again later."
        }
      ]
    },
    "score": 1
  },
  "status": {
    "code": 200,
    "errorType": "success",
    "webhookTimedOut": false
  },
  "sessionId": "24069c06-d6c0-4723-a0d9-fa284884d023"
}
```

Google Actions Testing Logs **FAIL**

```
{
  "request": {
    "conversationToken": "",
    "debugLevel": 1,
    "inputType": "KEYBOARD",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "mockLocation": {
      "city": "Mountain View",
      "coordinates": {
        "latitude": 37.421980615353675,
        "longitude": -122.08419799804688
      },
      "formattedAddress": "Googleplex, Mountain View, CA 94043, United States",
      "zipCode": "94043"
    },
    "query": "ask follow up to log a call",
    "surface": "GOOGLE_HOME"
  },
  "response": {
    "conversationToken": "GidzaW11bG...",
    "response": "Follow up isn't responding right now. Try again soon.",
    "visualResponse": {
      "visualElements": []
    }
  },
  "debug": {
    "agentToAssistantDebug": {
      "agentToAssistantJson": "{\"message\":\"Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse, exception thrown with message: Empty speech response\",\"apiResponse\":{\"id\":\"49c16313-09e6-4431-9765-37095a19e3bb\",\"timestamp\":\"2018-01-31T01:45:41.734Z\",\"lang\":\"en-us\",\"result\":{},\"status\":{\"code\":200,\"errorType\":\"success\"},\"sessionId\":\"1517363140452\"}}"
    },
    "assistantToAgentDebug": {
      "assistantToAgentJson": "{\"user\":{\"userId\":\"ABwppHGKOxCmVg53MPiRI_5NnIt0vUjDf0Hqwxgm9pTNnH8vOquUymEX8T2OtFC1NA48-X4JiKBTk0an2wTYVw\",\"accessToken\":\"{\\\"access_token\\\":\\\"00D36000000uHY5!AQoAQFHFHGAYHInuT1.FtcUSN7k81w1tgkEh.ijyqq1Pw3UqtlCM6SGi_qTrvFDAvPBG673Lgr119bpIUEUNuOnC4XF2d7o2\\\",\\\"refresh_token\\\":\\\"5Aep861QbHyftz0nI9mDOXbILtyhnTRY2lNmFwvaIHwc6w_JBasCpmEoOoWUo5W9asHeibIB9HbomiclZ2P_6pk\\\",\\\"signature\\\":\\\"nUZJxL8SFUVOScLjP6c5ydpjwL8iLRyHZ+xOyehfLhc=\\\",\\\"scope\\\":\\\"refresh_token web api\\\",\\\"instance_url\\\":\\\"https://follow-up-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com\\\",\\\"id\\\":\\\"https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D36000000uHY5EAM/00536000000L9ePAAS\\\",\\\"token_type\\\":\\\"Bearer\\\",\\\"issued_at\\\":\\\"1517363133651\\\"}\",\"locale\":\"en-US\",\"lastSeen\":\"2018-01-31T01:44:48Z\"},\"conversation\":{\"conversationId\":\"1517363140452\",\"type\":\"NEW\"},\"inputs\":[{\"intent\":\"Log Call by Name\",\"rawInputs\":[{\"inputType\":\"VOICE\",\"query\":\"ask follow up to log a call\"}],\"arguments\":[{\"name\":\"trigger_query\",\"rawText\":\"log a call\",\"textValue\":\"log a call\"},{\"name\":\"Type\",\"rawText\":\"call\",\"textValue\":\"call\"}]}],\"surface\":{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO\"}]},\"isInSandbox\":true,\"availableSurfaces\":[{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"}]}]}",
      "curlCommand": "curl -v 'https://api.api.ai/api/integrations/google?token=1ee421e5c9504f5b995ce9df62f7d275' -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -H 'Google-Actions-API-Version: 2' -H 'Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjI2YzAxOGIyMzNmZTJlZWY0N2ZlZGJiZGQ5Mzk4MTcwZmM5YjI5ZDgifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJzYWxlc2ZvcmNlLWEwOWVkIiwiYXpwIjoiMTE4NDUyMTUyMjE5LW1zZ2VldXBkaGU5YWp0MzZpNnJxbHJtdTExZGQ1Y2gyLmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNTE3MzYzMjYwLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FjY291bnRzLmdvb2dsZS5jb20iLCJqdGkiOiI5NDQxOTU4YzVkYWY3ZjgyODkzOTdhYWRkNjgzMzNmNDQ1ZjY2NDFkIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE3MzYzMTQwLCJuYmYiOjE1MTczNjI4NDB9.Fc5SWQakdTwfhW3x1NGgbwzT4pjec5GW2fOVc0Vh9aZ8XseAOeMWDRdiVK5Q4ApRMfJWC239P2LYvXGzW2tqZBPjxS_LKdD_6GbRJaNAYMs2SyiTuJmLs0G9RqFzXja-0mz8q_lejpWSuLgjzO7H136lHjR4d6bFiNS0ec3UIzIrgx7oaGCtRFuEtj4af82llyztaKkDAtwpankG01CBWm_sX_FmFD9svLUk7u22NA3KXsCM23fasLcmietBEj6LktnfiR6Tk85mk4n5FYi4VJ7KHzsfgIPC2zkmJVaAc1OczLvV_qtLb_9hoM_3k8jLMXK0n1oypQHZSpCvElOzwQ'  -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Cloud-Functions/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)' -X POST -d '{\"user\":{\"userId\":\"ABwppHGKOxCmVg53MPiRI_5NnIt0vUjDf0Hqwxgm9pTNnH8vOquUymEX8T2OtFC1NA48-X4JiKBTk0an2wTYVw\",\"accessToken\":\"{\\\"access_token\\\":\\\"00D36000000uHY5!AQoAQFHFHGAYHInuT1.FtcUSN7k81w1tgkEh.ijyqq1Pw3UqtlCM6SGi_qTrvFDAvPBG673Lgr119bpIUEUNuOnC4XF2d7o2\\\",\\\"refresh_token\\\":\\\"5Aep861QbHyftz0nI9mDOXbILtyhnTRY2lNmFwvaIHwc6w_JBasCpmEoOoWUo5W9asHeibIB9HbomiclZ2P_6pk\\\",\\\"signature\\\":\\\"nUZJxL8SFUVOScLjP6c5ydpjwL8iLRyHZ+xOyehfLhc=\\\",\\\"scope\\\":\\\"refresh_token web api\\\",\\\"instance_url\\\":\\\"https://follow-up-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com\\\",\\\"id\\\":\\\"https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D36000000uHY5EAM/00536000000L9ePAAS\\\",\\\"token_type\\\":\\\"Bearer\\\",\\\"issued_at\\\":\\\"1517363133651\\\"}\",\"locale\":\"en-US\",\"lastSeen\":\"2018-01-31T01:44:48Z\"},\"conversation\":{\"conversationId\":\"1517363140452\",\"type\":\"NEW\"},\"inputs\":[{\"intent\":\"Log Call by Name\",\"rawInputs\":[{\"inputType\":\"VOICE\",\"query\":\"ask follow up to log a call\"}],\"arguments\":[{\"name\":\"trigger_query\",\"rawText\":\"log a call\",\"textValue\":\"log a call\"},{\"name\":\"Type\",\"rawText\":\"call\",\"textValue\":\"call\"}]}],\"surface\":{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO\"}]},\"isInSandbox\":true,\"availableSurfaces\":[{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"}]}]}'"
    },
    "sharedDebugInfo": [
      {
        "name": "ResponseValidation",
        "subDebugEntry": [
          {
            "debugInfo": "API Version 2: Failed to parse JSON response string with 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' error: \": Cannot find field.\".",
            "name": "UnparseableJsonResponse"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "errors": [
    [
      {
        "debugInfo": "API Version 2: Failed to parse JSON response string with 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' error: \": Cannot find field.\".",
        "name": "UnparseableJsonResponse"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Google Cloud Logs **SUCCESS** Post

```
    {
     insertId:  "epw74xfuhr98a"  
     labels: {
      channel:  "preview"   
      source:  "JSON_RESPONSE_VALIDATION"   
     }
     logName:  "projects/salesforce-a09ed/logs/actions.googleapis.com%2Factions"  
     receiveTimestamp:  "2018-01-31T02:07:08.026897050Z"  
     resource: {
      labels: {
       action_id:  ""    
       project_id:  "salesforce-a09ed"    
       version_id:  ""    
      }
      type:  "assistant_action"   
     }
     severity:  "DEBUG"  
     textPayload:  "Sending request with post data: {"user":{"userId":"ABwppHGKOxCmVg53MPiRI_5NnIt0vUjDf0Hqwxgm9pTNnH8vOquUymEX8T2OtFC1NA48-X4JiKBTk0an2wTYVw","accessToken":"{\"access_token\":\"00D36000000uHY5!AQoAQPlRWyuv4mA0oNyUUcUWBr1PRzsaQB0NGFR3f9CD6j4Z_vHGSHCcRtGyOet5F_jEdvo.ykj1es.d2y.d7lFwanc1x1en\",\"refresh_token\":\"5Aep861QbHyftz0nI9mDOXbILtyhnTRY2lNmFwvaIHwc6w_JBZrL0KU0BZ3nLp.5Q1bBdSVn.zL53m3QsG0ZW1J\",\"signature\":\"UncpON0wsMm9OfoudbJw4liWBdWktyCat6lxArAO3iU=\",\"scope\":\"refresh_token web api\",\"instance_url\":\"https://follow-up-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com\",\"id\":\"https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D36000000uHY5EAM/00536000000L9ePAAS\",\"token_type\":\"Bearer\",\"issued_at\":\"1517364271309\"}","locale":"en-US","lastSeen":"2018-01-31T02:05:39Z"},"conversation":{"conversationId":"1517364426179","type":"NEW"},

"inputs":[{"intent":"actions.intent.MAIN","rawInputs":[{"inputType":"VOICE","query":"open follow-up"}]}],

"surface":{"capabilities":[{"name":"actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO"},{"name":"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"}]},"isInSandbox":true,"availableSurfaces":[{"capabilities":[{"name":"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"},{"name":"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"}]}]}."  
     timestamp:  "2018-01-31T02:07:06.435444389Z"  
     trace:  "projects/118452152219/traces/1517364426179"  
    }
```

Google Cloud Logs **FAIL** Post

```
 {
     insertId:  "5kahhnfa51fzb"  
     labels: {
      channel:  "preview"   
      source:  "JSON_RESPONSE_VALIDATION"   
     }
     logName:  "projects/salesforce-a09ed/logs/actions.googleapis.com%2Factions"  
     receiveTimestamp:  "2018-01-31T02:08:18.510485438Z"  
     resource: {
      labels: {
       action_id:  ""    
       project_id:  "salesforce-a09ed"    
       version_id:  ""    
      }
      type:  "assistant_action"   
     }
     severity:  "DEBUG"  
     textPayload:  "Sending request with post data: {"user":{"userId":"ABwppHGKOxCmVg53MPiRI_5NnIt0vUjDf0Hqwxgm9pTNnH8vOquUymEX8T2OtFC1NA48-X4JiKBTk0an2wTYVw","accessToken":"{\"access_token\":\"00D36000000uHY5!AQoAQPlRWyuv4mA0oNyUUcUWBr1PRzsaQB0NGFR3f9CD6j4Z_vHGSHCcRtGyOet5F_jEdvo.ykj1es.d2y.d7lFwanc1x1en\",\"refresh_token\":\"5Aep861QbHyftz0nI9mDOXbILtyhnTRY2lNmFwvaIHwc6w_JBZrL0KU0BZ3nLp.5Q1bBdSVn.zL53m3QsG0ZW1J\",\"signature\":\"UncpON0wsMm9OfoudbJw4liWBdWktyCat6lxArAO3iU=\",\"scope\":\"refresh_token web api\",\"instance_url\":\"https://follow-up-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com\",\"id\":\"https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D36000000uHY5EAM/00536000000L9ePAAS\",\"token_type\":\"Bearer\",\"issued_at\":\"1517364271309\"}","locale":"en-US","lastSeen":"2018-01-31T02:08:07Z"},"conversation":{"conversationId":"1517364498025","type":"NEW"},

"inputs":[{"intent":"ReminderIntent","rawInputs":[{"inputType":"VOICE","query":"ask follow up to create a reminder"}],"arguments":[{"name":"trigger_query","rawText":"create a reminder","textValue":"create a reminder"},{"name":"Task","rawText":"creates","textValue":"create"},{"name":"Task","rawText":"reminders","textValue":"reminder"}]}],

"surface":{"capabilities":[{"name":"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"},{"name":"actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO"}]},"isInSandbox":true,"availableSurfaces":[{"capabilities":[{"name":"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"},{"name":"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"}]}]}."  
     timestamp:  "2018-01-31T02:08:18.282416932Z"  
     trace:  "projects/118452152219/traces/1517364498025"  
    }
```

Screen shots:

- [DialogFlow Welcome Intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVhO1.png)
- [DialogFlow LogCall Intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waghB.png)
- [DialogFlow / Assistant Integration Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52FlE.png)
- [Google Actions Simulator error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QThb5.png)
- [Google Cloud Error Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0Bji.png)

Comment: Can you update the question to include a screen shot of the Google Assistant Integration screen on DialogFlow?

Comment: It looks like your "Log Call by Name" requires a certain input context to run. Since you initially invoke the Google Assistant to your intent, it will not have that context set and that intent will not run.

Comment: @Prisoner okay I have added the screenshot of the integrations tab. I have tried it with the boxes checked and unchecked but same result.

Comment: @NickFelker I feel like you're onto something but the request is not hitting my Webhook for AWS Lambda - the error is at the Google Cloud Platform level. Take a look at the Google Cloud Error Logs screenshot

Comment: @NickFelker @Prisoner okay I finally found in the Google Cloud Logs the difference in the request to my app - I broke out the `intent` part from the `textPayload` and it is clearly different. On the fail side I am getting `"intent":"ReminderIntent"` or `"intent":"Log Call by Business"` but on the standard Invocation success side I am getting `"intent":"actions.intent.MAIN"` Is this a bug? My action names for these intents are `add.reminder` and `Create.logCallByBusiness`

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because the intent you are trying to match "Log call by name" which expects an input context "sessionData", will never be matched because invoking your app using a deep-link "ask follow up to log a call" doesn't send that context in the request. That explains why your default response (Text response) for that intent isn't returned.

To fix it you need to:

- Remove the input contexts from the intents you intend to use as deep-links OR duplicate those intents and remove the input contexts from the duplicates.
- **Best practice 1**: Have a fallback intent that has no input contexts, which will catch any unmatched in-dialog queries.
- **Best practice 2**: Have a fallback intent that specifically handles unmatched deep-links at invocation time. (See image below)

[image: Unrecognized deep-link fallback]

Comment: If you already have a 'Default Welcome Intent' with no contexts and 'Welcome' in it's events, would you have to delete this intent to get the 'Unrecognized deep link fallback intent' to work? I have both intents enabled and the unrecognized deep link fallback intent isn't getting triggered.

Answer (score 1):

The `agentToAssistantJson` field has an encoded JSON entry for `result` which typically suggests that your webhook isn't returning anything. Normally, Dialogflow returns the static messages you've defined in the Intent in this case, but it sounds like that isn't happening here. Verify that the URL you're using for fulfillment is correct and that it is returning valid JSON.

In this case, I think there are a few things that could be causing the problem.

The phrase "Ask follow up to log a call" *should* be triggering the `Log Call by Name` Intent it looks like. But this Intent isn't listed as one of the implicit invocation Intents. The Assistant might be passing this off to Dialogflow, and Dialogflow, finding no match, returns nothing.

But even if it did match the phrasing for the `Log Call by Name` Intent, and that Intent was an implicit invocation Intent, there are two other elements of the Intent that seem strange.

The first is that the Intent is expecting an input context of `sessionData`. But since this is meant to be used as an initial Intent, there can be no input context. Dialogflow may be told by the Assistant that this is the matching Intent, and then reject it because the input context doesn't match.

Similarly, the second oddity is that you're looking for an event called `CALL_BY_NAME`. Events generally override any phrases that may be spoken - they're meant to capture non-textual activities (the WELCOME intent, for example, or an option being selected, or the user saying nothing). Unless you're triggering the event (which you can do), you probably wouldn't want it. As above, I'm wondering if the Assistant is telling Dialogflow this is the Intent to use, but Dialogflow isn't getting the event, so rejects it and sends back nothing.

**tl;dr**

There are three possible things to look at and fix:

1. Make sure the Intent is listed as an implicit invocation Intent in the Assistant Integration.
2. Remove the incoming context.
3. Remove the event.

Comment: Well the webhook is up and fine - if I say "Talk to Follow Up" it successfully hits the Webhook and invokes the Welcome intent. I see this in my AWS Lambda logs. But when I say "Hey google, ask Follow Up to Log a Call" I get the topline error. Considering I have a default response in the Intent this makes me think that there is malformed JSON between DialogFlow and Google Cloud (before its routed to AWS). I have added the "Success" logs for the invoking the Welcome intent to the post for comparison. Any additional thoughts?

Comment: Well... there are some additional thoughts. {:

Comment: commented on the other thread but here as well - I broke out the intent part from the textPayload and it is clearly different. On the fail side I am getting `"intent":"ReminderIntent"` or `"intent":"Log Call by Business"` but on the standard Invocation success side I am getting `"intent":"actions.intent.MAIN"` Is this a bug? My action names for these intents are `add.reminder` and `Create.logCallByBusiness`

Comment: Also if I invoke the app via default welcome, then invoke the `Log a call` intent, the textPayload has `"inputs":[{"intent":"actions.intent.TEXT"` @Prisoner

Comment: I'm not sure how this relates to my answer, but perhaps update your question with it? At any rate - I think this is a red herring that is misleading you. The intent names between what the Assistant calls the Intent and what Dialogflow calls the Intent, not to mention the Action name in Dialogflow, can all be different.